# Why error is caught when calling to a missing function, and not on a bad statements?

Tags: javascript

Please see this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="P1"></p>

<script>
try {
    alllllllert("Hello.........!");
}
catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML = err.message;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When this code is running an error is caugth and I enter the catch block.

However, why this is not happaning in the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="P1"></p>

<script>
try {
    int n = 3;
    document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML = n;

}
catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML = err.message;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Writing int n = 3 cannot compile on JavaScript, and I know I need to write var n =3. So, why don't I get an exception with a message?

Comment: Because you have a **syntax** error. The code can't even execute. Consider this analogy: *"Why is the engine control light not flashing when my car doesn't have an engine?"*. You can't even start the car without an engine (I assume), so the light can never show up.

Comment: Because a syntax error isn't an exception, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Because runtime exceptions are different than compiler errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int n = 3;` is invalid syntax, which prevents your entire `<script>` block from being parsed.

Therefore, your `catch` block doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the first example, `alllllllert("Hello.........!");`, you actually have valid JavaScript.  This makes it a runtime exception, because the code still parsed correctly and the error wasn't discovered until the engine actually tried to locate the function to invoke.

The second example, `int n = 3;` isn't valid JavaScript at all.  This causes the parser to puke and throw an error before even trying to run the code.  Try/catch are runtime constructs that can only catch runtime errors.